# Как в языке Си вывести результат работы функции в терминал?

Tags: c

Есть функция на языке Си, например такая

`int id(int x){
  return x;
}`

Как можно вызвать ее с печатью результата в терминал? В JS можно сделать так

```
console.log(id(1));
```

Как такое сделать в Си?

`Update:` Благодаря пользователю `AnT` кое-что получилось. С помощью такого кода удалось вывести результат работы функции в терминал:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int id(int x){
  return x;
}

int main (void)
{

  int x = 1; 
  int (*operation)(int x);
  int result;

  operation = id;
  result = operation(x);

  printf("result = %d \n", result);

  return 0;
}
```

Но мне кажется такой код избыточным. Может быть можно избавиться от лишнего? И теперь аргумент функции переменная, а я бы хотел передавать аргумент при вызове функции.

Comment: Читать `man printf`

Comment: Почитаю, спасибо. Я не понимаю типизацию в Си. Функции вообще можно передавать как аргументы?

Comment: конечно  можно. Во всех учебниках и справочниках описано. Не говоря уже о том, что в поисковике легко найти

Comment: Конечно можно это передавать функции как аргументы или что?

Comment: А простых решений не предлагать? `printf("result = %d \n", id(x));`

Comment: @NewView большое спасибо. Это то что нужно.

Comment: Как правильно заметил @AnT, читать документацию, в `C` команда printf делиться на две части: 1. строковое описание выводимых значений по типам ("%s,%d,%u,%x итд") и вторая часть сами источники значений, это могут быть как переменные, так и функци, в том числе и любые математические операции и выражения, например: `(id(x) + 7)` . Собственно это описано в документации.

Comment: Ну блин, про printf и про %d пишут в абсолютно каждом учебнике по Си

Comment: @andreymal вот бы их ещё кто-нибудь читал!

Comment: Вообще-то на `printf` основана всем известная программа HelloWorld, так что проехать мимо этой функции это надо еще суметь.

Comment: Чтобы в `printf` передать функцию, нужно передать еще и параметры формата. Этого я не знал, поэтому код не работал.

Comment: Параметры формата передавать не нужно если функция возвращает указатель на строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
printf("%d", id(5));
```

Аргумент "%d" можно менять в зависимости от возвращаемого типа.

Answer (score 1):

Таким способом вы сделали указатель на функцию

```
int (*operation)(int x);
```

Тогда чтобы вызвать эту функцию надо писать так.

```
int phenix ( int x )
{
  return x;
}
operation = phenix;
```

А чтобы потом вывести результат, то надо написать так.

```
int result = operation ( x );
```

И вызвать printf

```
%d - целые числа
%s - строка
%c - символ
%x - шестнадцатеричное число
```

Можно сделать такую функцию

```
void print_int ( int x )
{
  printf ( "log: %d\n", x );
}
```

И вызывать её вот так.

```
print_int ( x );
```